# Nodejs and Sphinx data query issue

Tags: node.js, sphinx, npm

I have been using limestone module and Nodejs to query sphinx index. The limestone is out-dated in my npm so i downloaded from github and it is got connected to the sphinx server successfully. But i am now facing the issue as follows,

When i tried to execute the following code,

```
 var limestone = require("limestone").SphinxClient(),
    sys = require("sys");

    limestone.connect("192.168.2.443:9312", // port. 9312 is standard Sphinx port. also 'host:port' allowed
    function(err) { 
      if (err) {
          sys.puts('Connection error: ' + err);
      }

      sys.puts('Connected, sending query');
      limestone.query(            
         {'query':'raja',maxmatches:1},
          function(err, answer) {

            if(err){
                console.log("Sphinx ERR: "+err);
            }else{

                console.log(JSON.stringify(answer));
              limestone.disconnect();

            }             
          });       
     });
```

i got the below error,

```
Sphinx ERR: Searchd command older than client's version, some options might not workServer issued ERROR: 0bad multi-query count 0 (must be in 1..32 range)
```

Please help me on this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I installed `sphinxseach` on Ubuntu, the version in the repository is `0.9.9`. I got a similar error as yours:

> `Searchd command older than client's version, some options might not workServer issued ERROR: Qclient version is higher than daemon version (client is v.1.24, daemon is v.1.22) undefined`

After looking through the issues at [limestone's github](https://github.com/kurokikaze/limestone/issues), I figured it was supposed to work with Sphinx version 2. So I installed `2.0.4` from [Sphinx download page](http://sphinxsearch.com/downloads/release/) (they have Ubuntu packages), and it works! So, if it's possible for you to upgrade, that might be a good idea anyway -- and limestone will probably only ever track the latest release.

Comment: Hi, Finally i have upgraded my sphinx version to 2.0.4 and ran the above file and i got the another error as follows, 
"Searchd command older than client's version, some options might not work
Server issued ERROR:: 0bad multi-query count 0 (must be in 1..32 range)"

Comment: Strange - to be 100% clear, limestone master and sphinx 2.0.4 worked for me, with a simple `{query: "foo", maxmatches: 1}`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment. It works for me now after changing the Sphinx.clientCommand value in limestone.js :

Comment: Changed values in limestone.js is as follows,

"SEARCH" : 0x118,
"EXCERPT" : 0x103